Middleware can not access the cookie after deployment but locally it can access the cookies in next js
I have a NextJS application as a frontend application; for the backend, I am using the NodeJS ExpressJS application. Here, I implemented JWT token-based authentication and authorization. So I am setting the only JWT token from the backend server. On the frontend server, I am accessing the token. If I can access the token from the NextJS app, then I permit users to access private routes. So my problem is that when I am running my applications locally, they are running well, and I have not faced any issues. But after deployment, it has been setting cookies in the frontend browser well, but it can not send cookies when I am trying to access private routes from the frontend. MiddlewareJS cannot access the cookies.
middleware.js in next js application :
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import react from 'react';

const middleware = (req) => {

    let verify = req.cookies.get("jwt")
    let url = req.url
    if (!verify && url.includes("/dashboard")) {
       
        return NextResponse.redirect(`${process.env.NEXT_URL}/login`);
    }

};
export default middleware;

index.js  cors in express application :
if(process.env.NODE_ENV==="Production"){
  corsOptions = {
    credentials: true, origin:process.env.ORIGIN_URL 
  };
}else{
  corsOptions = {
    credentials: true, origin:true
  };
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

protectMiddleware in express js application :
const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  token=req.cookies?.jwt
  console.log(token)
  if (token) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      console.log(decoded)
      req.user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
        where: {
          email: decoded.email,
        },

      });
      next();
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error(`Not Authorized, Invalid Token`);
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error(`Not Authorized, No Token`);
  }
});

Note : Here my Next js and backend are in different domain backend and frontend are running in https.
How can it be run without issue after deployment and middleware js will access the cookie into the next js application after deployment?
is there any solution ?
Thank you so much .

what is ORIGIN_URL it is full url or just domain

ORIGIN_URL is my frontend domain

Have you tried accessing cookies using cookies from next/headers?
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const middleware = (req) => {
   const cookieStore = cookies();
   const verify = cookieStore.get('jwt');

   // The rest of your code
};

export default middleware;


Tried but didn't work
